# Tomcat 7 java.net.SocketException connecting to LDAP

Tags: ldap

I have a project in Eclipse running Tomcat v7.0 trying to connect to ldap server.  Everything is setup the same as a co-worker's and hers works fine but mine won't seem to connect. I edited it with xxxx where necessary.  Below is the error I get when trying to login.

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: win.eng.xxxx.com:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:214)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:136)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1600)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2698)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:316)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:211)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:101)
    at com.vzwcorp.ESNHandSet.ESNLogin.authenticate(ESNLogin.java:85)
    at com.vzwcorp.ESNHandSet.ESNLogin.authenticate(ESNLogin.java:56)
    at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:112)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:407)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
    at com.vzwcorp.ESNHandSet.DummySSLSocketFactory.createSocket(DummySSLSocketFactory.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.createSocket(Connection.java:331)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:201)
    ... 38 more
userAgent=Firefox/32.0
Trying to get a connection, current active connections: 0
Connection returned in ms: 0
login: User myname failed to authenticate.
```

Comment: 'Network is unreachable' should be fairly clear, surely. This is not a programming problem.

Comment: yeah - the overall issue turned out to be ipv6

Answer (score 0):

okay - after finally tracking down 'that guy' we determined the ldap server wasn't reachable from my location in the network and had to switch to a different one and now it work's.